# Android equivalent of vb.net StringValue.ToString("0000")

Tags: java, android, string

Is there an equivilent of vb.nets StringValue.ToString("0000") so that it returns the string as four numbers. I'm trying to work it on :

```
public static String getNextID(int stationID, String tablename) {

        String rtnID;
        rtnID = Integer.toString(stationID) + "-" + getNextID(tablename);

        return rtnID;

    }
```

So that the value of rtnID is 4 characters long and it's added 0's in the right place if needed

Tom

Edit: heres what I now have that isn't working:

```
public static String getNextID(int stationID, String tablename) {

    String rtnID;
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000");
    String s = formatter.format(String.valueOf(stationID)); 
    rtnID = s + "-" + getNextID(tablename);

    return rtnID;

}
```

With this error: http://pastebin.com/XpvzkC5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000");
String s = formatter.format(stationID);
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this. I think I must be doing something wrong as it falls over (i've updated my answer with what i've done and the error)